# Routing in subdirectory in Angular.js

Tags: url-routing, angularjs

Is it possible to develop an Angular.js application in a way that would be abstracted from the the web directory path in which it will be deployed?

I am trying to put an Angular.js app in a web server subdirectory http://example.com/myproject/, but the router redirects me to the web server root -- http://example.com.

Below is my Angular.js app:

```js
var myproject = angular.module('myproject', []);

myproject.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
    when('/', {templateUrl: 'partials/index.html', controller: IndexCtrl}).
    otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});

  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});



function IndexCtrl($scope, $location) {

}
```

Comment: plus one for the user name :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try setting a `<base href="/sudirectory"/>` in your `<head></head>`. That's what I needed to do to get mine working, IIRC

Word of caution: This will mess with any anchor tags that have href="#", as well as act as the root for image srcs and the like.

Comment: Another tip that could potentially help: don't forget to use relative paths instead of absolute for the router partial template resources, after setting <base>.

Comment: Works for relative paths, but I have AJAX calls that are specified as 'getSomething/'which would work except I needed to set them as '/getSomething/' since it would otherwise get appended to the URL which may have other routing information in it. I want the AJAX calls to resolve to 'mydomain/getSomething/' but if my Angular router has me at 'mydomain/article/1/' it gets appended. I had no choice but to create a global base_url variable and prepend it to all my AJAX URLs. Would be nice to just set this as a config within Angular, but luckily the project is small enough to just do by hand.