# Using a Relative Path for a Service Call in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code, which was working fine until I deployed to a test server:

```
$scope.getUserList = function (userName) {
    $http({
        method: "get",
        url: "GetUserList",
        params: { userName: userName }
    }).
        success(function (data) {
            $scope.users = data;
        }).
        error(function () {
            alert("Error getting users.");
```

The problem is that I deployed to a virtual directory, and the call below is attempting to hit GetUserList from the server root.  This makes sense, and I know a number of ways to fix it.

What I would like to know is the *right* way to reference the service URL in a way that is portable and maintainable in Angular.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

I'd suggest using an HTML base tag in the head, and coding all paths relative to this. In ASP.NET, for example, you can get a reference to the base of the application, which may or may not be the root path of the site, so using a base tag helps. Bonus: it works for every other asset too.

You can have a base path like this:

```
<base href="/application_root/" />
```

...and then links like "foo/bar.html" will actually be /application_root/foo/bar.html.

Another approach I like to use is to put named links in the header. I will often have an API root in one location and a directive template root somewhere else. In the head, I'll then add some tags like this:

```
<link id="linkApiRoot" href="/application_root/api/"/>
<link id="linkTemplateRoot" href="/application_root/Content/Templates/"/>
```

... and then use $provide in the module to get the link href and expose it to services and directives like so:

```
angular.module("app.services", [])
    .config(["$provide", function ($provide) {
        $provide.value("apiRoot", $("#linkApiRoot").attr("href"));
    }]);
```

... and then inject it to a service like this:

```
angular.module("app.services").factory("myAdminSvc", ["apiRoot", function (apiRoot) {
    var apiAdminRoot = apiRoot + "admin/";
    ...
```

Just my opinion though. Do the least complex thing for your application.

Comment: Maybe it is better to use $provide.constant instead of $provide.value? Constants are available also during configuration phase (for example during routing). What do you think?

Comment: But how do you deal with the testing `localhost:####`? Wouldn't it be better if we store the base url in `Web.Config` (so that we can transform when publishing) instead of in the `<header>` section?

Comment: You create a dependency on jQuery by using         `$provide.value("apiRoot", $("#linkApiRoot").attr("href"));`
Instead you could use plain javascript, spiced with some jqLite:
`var elem = angular.element(document.querySelector('#linkApiRoot'));
$provide.value("apiRoot", elem.attr("href"));`

Comment: Thanks for the tip, just had the same problem when switching from IIS Express to local IIS. But instead of hard coding the base url, I just inserted the default action.
`<base href="@Url.Action("Home", "Index")" />`
And it works as expected!!

Comment: I'm in the exact same situation as the TS, however `<base>` seems to have no effect on my angular `$http.get` calls, only on html links.

Comment: Update on previous comment: If the path in `$http.get('/api/app/' + action)` starts with a forward slash, as in this example, the base tag is ignored. Right way is:  `$http.get('api/app/' + action)`.

Comment: Also, instead of setting the `<base>` tag in the html head, the same href can be added in the angular code by overiding the browser baseHref method in the app modules `run()` function, like this: `$browser.baseHref = function() { return "/application_root/" };`

Comment: On my project, adding base tag was sufficient for Angular services to find their relative way to /appi/xxx

Comment: Big thanks to @DonSimon! Removing the leading slash / solved my problem and allowed me to hit my API successfully. I didn't have to do any of the other things described in this post.

Answer (score 29):

I would suggest defining a module that contains a global config that you can then pass around your application:

```
// Module specific configuration
angular.module('app.config')
  .value('app.config', {
    basePath: '/' // Set your base path here
  });
```

Then you can access this from anywhere within your application thanks to AngularJS dependency injection:

```
// Make sure your config is included in your module
angular.module('app', ['app.config']);

// Access your config e.g. in a controller
angular.module('app')
  .controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope','app.config', function($scope, config){

    // Use config base path to assemble url
    $scope.url = config.basePath + 'GetUserList';
    ...
  }]);
```

Whenever the base path changes (e.g. when you change to another server or host), you just need to change it in your global config and you're done.

Comment: I like this. One path is seldom enough; you may have template paths, API paths, etc.

Comment: Indeed, you can add as many properties as you like to your config and use them anywhere in your application.

Comment: @jvandemo While resolving the config dependency, how does angular know  that config refers to app.config, same what I have always wondered how angular knows ng refers to angular, does it use the order of the parameters?

Comment: Exactly what I needed to glue my AngularJS app with Symfony2! Thanks for sharing!

Comment: This answer seems easy but in terms of re-usability is actually poor. In order for you to use your module in another application you'd also be required to use this app.config module as well.

Comment: Though it's worth noting that this is the only answer that actually has any sort of success. The important point is to use a function for your templateUrl. Also, i couldn't get app.config to work so changed everything to 'config'. Then you can pass it into your templateUrl, after making sure to declare your module dependent on this module, like so: ['config', function(config){ return config.basePath + (your relative path) }]. In addition, this only works if you have a means of identifying the basePath. I was lucky and could use razor in my layout file.

Answer (score 13):

I wasn't able to use `<base>` tag since my application was created in a popup dynamically from another origion. I was considering the others option in this thread to use something like a basePath variable and use it in every `$http, ng-src, templateUrl` etc

But that was a bit overhead, built a interceptor that change every url before a xhr is made

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.config(["$httpProvider", function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('middleware');
}]);

app.factory('middleware', function() {
    return {
        request: function(config) {
            // need more controlling when there is more than 1 domain involved
            config.url = "//example.com/api/" + config.url
            return config;
        }
    };
});

app.controller("Ctrl", ["$http", function($http) {
    $http.get("books"); // actually requestUrl = http://example.com/api/books
}])
```

And html aswell

```
<div ng-include src="'view'">
    <!-- actually src = http://example.com/api/view -->
</div>
```

But i do recommend to use `<base>` tag instead unless you are using window.popup()

Comment: This is a great solution! BUT, when you fetch views via xhr it will use this provided url!

Comment: @ammt I know, that was my intentions

Comment: There any way you can use this middleware with only `$http`? but not with ng-include/template. Because I want to have an relative path for my api.

Comment: @MaicolBen you can prefix your api and validate the URL so that it starts with /api/.../ or something. Otherwise ngResorce might be the best option

Answer (score 4):

Use the $location service - it will return your path, the hash, the server address.. Everything you need! Your call would be to `$location.path()+"/GetUserList"` or something similar.

See here: [http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.$location](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.%24location)

Comment: $location.path() always seems to be blank.  I just inject it into my controller like this, or something else I need to do?  var saController = function ($scope, $http, $location) {}

Comment: Sorry for late response, but in our app we configured $locationProvider to support html5Mode, and that seems to kicked it into gear. The code looks something like this: 
    `.config([
        '$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
            $locationProvider.html5Mode({
                enabled: true,
                requireBase: false
            });
        }
    ])`

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem 
I solve it with the just one line of code in my MVC page

```
<base href="~/" />
```

Comment: This is the simplest and best fix so far. This solved my typescript directive templateUrl: issue. Before I was using back ticks and adding my html to template:

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer helped me. I'm using Angular served up my an MVC app.
I took one extra step so that my baseUrl could be used within my angular controllers for web api calls or for accessing templates.

Using ng-init to set the baseUrl (from a server side populated value)

```
<html ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppController">
<head>
    <base href="{{baseUrl}}" ng-init="baseUrl = '@Model.BaseUrl'" />
</head>
```

Angular controller

```
    $scope.manageCustomerGroups = function () {
        openDialog($scope.baseUrl + 'content/templates/customerGroups.html');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way, I'm using ASP.NET Razor (Web MVC), so I  get the Application path and make it as the base of app.

```
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>Title</title>

<meta name="description" content="">
@{ var appPath = Request.ApplicationPath.ToString();
    if (!appPath.EndsWith("/")) {
        appPath = appPath + "/";
    }
}
<base href="@appPath" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just make all URL relative.

```
url: "../GetUserList",
```

*instead*

```
url: "GetUserList",
```

Hard coding for the, `<base href="/application_root/" />`  dose not sound good idea to me as you might need to change this environment to environment, and has dependency over virtual directory name.

Answer (score -1):

In the ng-init function pass a parameter that contains the value the virtual directory (int ASP.NET stored in Request.ApplicationPath).

```
<div ng-controller="ControllerName" ng-init="init('@Request.ApplicationPath')">
```

Inside the angular controller, use this value as prefix of URL in every http call. You can use this function to combine the paths

```
function combinePath(path1, path2) {
    if (path1 == null) {
        return path2;
    }
    var last = path1.slice(-1);
    var first = path2.charAt(0);

    if (last == '/' && first == '/') {
        path1 = path1.substring(0, path1.length - 1);
    }
    return path1 + path2;
}
```

Comment: Things are missing in this answer. What does the `init()` function do? How is it connected to the `combinePath()` function? And finally, how is it used in the service?