# prefix $http url

Tags: angularjs

I can't seem to find an answer to what seems like a reasonable question.

I am using the $http service to call web services for all of my app.  All of the server API is hosted at a particular address.  Is there any way in which I can get $http to always prefix the provided URL with the API server?

For example, if my API is at `http://myAPi/API/`, I would like to be able to call:

```
$http.get("User")...
```

as opposed to:

```
$http.get("http://myAPI/API/User")
```

And Angular prefixes the request with the server address.  The aim is to not have the URL spread throughout the app.

Is there a way to achieve this with Angular?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a Relative Path for a Service Call in AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17011616/using-a-relative-path-for-a-service-call-in-angularjs)

Comment: The possible duplicate details what I currently have - essentially the server location stored in a variable of some kind and prefixed manually to each call.  I'm looking for a way for the prefix to be automatically prefixed, if this is possible.

Answer (score 6):

It's an old question but I made a solution some time ago

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(apiInterceptor);
   });

// api url prefix
var API_URL = 'http://localhost:8080/';

function apiInterceptor ($q) {
  return {
    request: function (config) {
      var url = config.url;

      // ignore template requests
      if (url.substr(url.length - 5) == '.html') {
        return config || $q.when(config);
      }

      config.url = API_URL + config.url;
      return config || $q.when(config);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Since $http doesn't have a built-in way of handling this case (other than editing the angular.js source code), you can either wrap your $http in a service:

```
apiService.get('user'); //where the service defines the $http call and builds the URL
```

... or simply create an angular constant:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).constant('apiPrefix', 'http://myAPI/API/')

$http.get(apiPrefix + 'User')
```

Either way would result to "not have the URL spread throughout the app".

Answer (score -1):

It's possible to add an interceptor to the http provider.

```
// register the interceptor as a service
$provide.factory('myHttpInterceptor', function($q, dependency1, dependency2) {
  return {
    // optional method
    'request': function(config) {
      // do something on success
      return config || $q.when(config);
    }
}
```

Then you register your interceptor.

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor');
```

You just have to edit the config :)

Comment: Be careful doing that, templates are intercepted too. You don't want to load `/api/my_template.html`