# AngularJS and Virtual Paths

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs

How do you deal with Virtual Paths in AngularJS?

For example in my test environment, my base url is `http://localhost/AppName/` and in production the root becomes `http://www.mysite.com/`.

So in dev, a `$http.get` goes to say `http://localhost/AppName/Controller/Action` but in prod that path does not exist, it needs to be `http://www.mysite.com/Controller/Action`.

How do you deal with `$http` calls and also, unit tests when mocking the backend with `$httpBackend`?

I have tried this in the `_Layout.cshtml` (using ASP.NET MVC) but that does not work in the unit tests:

```
<script>
    (function () {
        'use strict';

        var app = angular.module('cs').value('urlHelper', {
            getUrl: function (url) {
                var basePath = '@VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/")';

                return basePath + url;
            }
        });
    }());
</script>
```

Also have tried:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('cs', []);

    app.run(['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
        $rootScope.basePath = '/';
    }]);

}());
```

Any ideas to not have to worry about switching the root path somewhere before deploying to prod?

Comment: Don't bother with domain name, start with `/`. It will automatically point to the right root.

Comment: @Mik378 - Are you saying to just make my requests in $http like so: `$http.get('/Controller/Action')` and that will work in both cases?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I'm working like that in my application.

Comment: In ASP.NET MVC, it does not work like that. `/` is the root of the application, not the virtual directory.

Comment: May help you (similar question): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17011616/using-a-relative-path-for-a-service-call-in-angularjs (even comparing to ASP.NET)

Comment: Concerning my first comment, you're right, I misread the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basePath can be a value on its own and urlHelper a service that depends on basePath.

in the server side generated page, your server will inject whatever value VirtualPathUtility finds and in your tests you will manually inject whatever works for you.

razor:

```
<script>
    angular.module('cs').value('basePath', '@VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/")');
</script>
```

other js file:

```
angular.module('cs').factory('urlHelper', function (basePath) {
    return {
        getUrl: function (url) {
            return basePath + url;
        }
    };
});
```

test:

```
var urlHelper;

beforeEach(function() {

    module(function($provide) {
        $provide.value('basePath', '/');
    });

    inject(function($injector) {
        urlHelper = $injector.get('urlHelper');
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample?