# in jsp using angularjs $http the url is unreadable code

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc

Here is my app.js:

```js
var loginModule = angular.module('loginModule',[]);
loginModule.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {    
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8';
}]);
loginModule.controller('loginCtrl',function ($scope,$http,$parse){
    $scope.signin_user = {name:"",password:""};
    $scope.errors = [];
    $scope.submit = function(){
        if($scope.login_form.$valid){
            var data ="name="+$scope.signin_user.name+"&password="+$scope.signin_user.password;
            $http({
                method:'post',
                url:'${ctx}/login',
                data:data
            })
            .success(function(data,status){
                console.log(data);
            })
            .error(function(data,status){
                console.log('status:'+status);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

In login.jsp I'm using jstl to get my web root,here is my tag.jsp, in login.jsp just include this file,which can use ${ctx} to get the web root.

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" pageEncoding="utf-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<c:set var="ctx" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath }" ></c:set>
```

But I don't understand what happend in the angularjs, using $htpp.post(url:'${ctx}/login'),just like app.js file.
And I use chrome developer tools to watch request url,I find the request url like this picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWgs2.png
the url was append other unreadable code.
I hope someone can fix it,thank all. If you can't see the picture, I would tell you in chrome developer tools the request url is 'localhost:8080/cloudaction/$%7Bctx%7D/login '

Answer (score 0):

I guess the content type on both side should be same then It would work.
Try from angularjs side setting content-type as "text/html" or both side "application/json".

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you cannot access to ${ctx} in your angular controller. In fact, the ${ctx} in your angular url is encoded in $%7Bctx%7D because angular don't know that it is a variable ( 
it is simply a string).
I think this post should be able to help you : [Using a Relative Path for a Service Call in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17011616/using-a-relative-path-for-a-service-call-in-angularjs)