# AngularJS $http request in provider function

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-http

I'm trying to implement client-side authentication with AngularJS. Right now I'm injecting the access-levels for each route as a factory into the config function of my app. Here is my code:

```
shop = angular.module('shop', ['ngCookies']).
provider('AccessLevels',function () {
    var accessLevels = {
        guest: 7,
        customer: 6,
        seller: 4
    };
    return {
        $get: function () {
            return accessLevels
        }
    }
}).
config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', 'AccessLevelsProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, AccessLevelsProvider) {

    var accessLevels = AccessLevelsProvider.$get();

    $routeProvider.
        when('/index', {templateUrl: "pages/index", controller: IndexController, access: accessLevels.guest}).
        when('/user', {templateUrl: "pages/user", controller: UserController, access: accessLevels.customer}).
        when('/sign_up', {templateUrl: "pages/sign_up", controller: SignUpController, access: accessLevels.guest});
}]);
```

Is it possible to get the data for my access-levels with a $http.get request? I can't inject $http into my provider function so I'm a little bit helpless at the moment.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the current version of AngularJS you can't inject `$http` into config blocks (more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12665051/1418796). On top of this config blocks are synchronous so calling async `$http` wouldn't work anyway.

Unfortunately there is no canonical way of re-defining routes based on the dynamic data. There are various work-arounds you could try, one of them is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13173667/1418796